# Nvim-tree not showing file specific icons

Tags: lua, neovim

I am following C@M ([nvim-from-scrach](https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch)).  Installed Nvim tree, Installed Jetbrains Nerd font. Installed nvim-web-devicons.

But i am not getting file specific icons in Nvim-tree. Its just showing default icons for *.lua files.

In-File icons are showing fine though.

here:

https://preview.redd.it/8catmqzd5p091.png?width=1392&format=png&auto=webp&s=f129ab4734b4b6818f58e9f88ed2d07f1210f624

My system info:

nvim: NVIM v0.7.0

Build type:

Release LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

Dots : https://github.com/shubmehetre/dotfiles/tree/master/.config/nvim

Comment: after installing the font have you also set it in your terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I just add Hack installed on my PC yet… So nvim did'nt use the good one.

Remove "non-nerd" ones resolved it.

Cheers,